# Windows 10 cant see ubuntu installed

Tags: boot, windows

After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, i would like to use the default windows boot loader to choose between Windows/Ubuntu. The problem is that windows is not detecting Ubuntu at all, ubuntu boot menu is working fine and even showing windows as option, but i would rather use the windows boot menu. Any known fixes? Thanks for your time

Comment: The Windows bootloader only recognizes and boots other Windows. There is nothing to fix because it's by design.

Comment: If you do not want to use grub, you can just use the UEFI boot menu to choose which system. If old BIOS system, better to use grub, but there are third party tools that can be installed in Windows ( really old grub4dos) to then boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, im not sure if it was bootloader or something else, but there always used to be windows themed option (after starting dualbooted pc) to choose which of os u wanted to boot, doesnt matter if windows or linux.
Screen like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A12nL.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using grub and find a theme to make it look like windows boot loader
https://www.pling.com/browse?cat=109&page=1&ord=latest

this one looks like windows 7 https://www.pling.com/p/1112066
if you can't find one you can try to make your own

Comment: That's a solid workaround, thank you!